# DateTime format with milliseconds for DevExpress control EditMask property

Tags: c#, devexpress

I need to display the date and time using devexpress DateEdit control. This can be achieved by setting the Mask for DateEdit Control. So, Currently I have taken the DateTime pattern from the current thread UI culture and set it to DevExpress DateEdit controls EditMask property.

The problem here is, I need to show the milliseconds also to the user. All the existing cultures does not have milliseconds in the DateTime pattern. So, I need to add the milliseconds field("fff") to the DateTime pattern of selected culture and set it to the DateEdit controls EditMask property.

My current code block is shown below,

```
var dateEdit = new DateEdit();
dateEdit.Properties.VistaDisplayMode = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
dateEdit.Properties.VistaEditTime = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
CultureInfo currentUiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
string editMask = currentUiCulture.DateTimeFormat.GeneralLongTimePattern;
dateEdit.Properties.EditMask = editMask;
```

Below are the DateTime pattern of some cultures and the expected pattern,

```
Culture     DateTime Pattern          Expected DateTime Pattern  
----------------------------------------------------------------
{en-US}     "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"     "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss.fff tt"         
{th-TH}     "d/M/yyyy H:mm:ss"        "d/M/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff"  
{sv-SE}     "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"     "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out :

```
// Append millisecond pattern to current culture's full date time pattern 
string fullPattern = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FullDateTimePattern;
fullPattern = Regex.Replace(fullPattern, "(:ss|:s)", "$1.fff");
```

Source : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882581.aspx)